# Pushing promise data to an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm probably not using promises correctly, but I'm calling a service (defined in a separate factory) into my controller like so,

```
_.each( $scope.aap.idList, function( id ){
    MyService.getItems( $stateParams.name, id ).$promise.then(
        function( scan ){
            if( scan.length !== 0){
                addToList( scan );
            }
        })
});

var addToList = function ( item ) {
    $scope.aap.scans.push( _.clone( item ) );
    return $scope.aap.scans;
};
```

The service is defined as:

```
    service.getItems = function ( name, id ) {
        var Items = $resource( '/proj/rs/pr/elems/getItems', {
            id: Id,
            name: name
        }, {
            query: {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: true,
                transformResponse: function ( scans ) {
                    var items = angular.fromJson( scans );
                    _.each( items, function ( scanItem ) {
                        scanItem.checked = false;
                    } );
                    return items;
                }
            }
        } );
        return Items.query();
```

Now, in `MyService.getItems` I can add a `console.log( scan )` and see the appropriate objects being passed through, but it won't add these items to my list. Is there some other way I should be going about this?

Comment: your function name `addToList()` is different to the function call within your promise `addItemsToList(  );`

Comment: Oops, that's leftovers from trying something else...I'll fix it.

Comment: I assume `item` (i.e. `scan`) is an array?

Comment: Yes, it's defined as `..scan = []`

Comment: Should `$scope.aap.scans` be a list of items or a list of arrays of items, which it is now?